# Getting an input value or JavaScript variable in ASP.NET MVC Ajax.ActionLink 

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass an input control value (say `textbox1.value` or a javascript variable) to a controller action method (as a parameter) without a form post (using Ajax.ActionLink). Please see the code below.

Is it possible to assign something like `new {name = textbox1.value}` in Ajax.ActionLink.

View

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1" />
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("mylink", "linkfunction", new {name = textbox1.value}, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result"}) %>
<span id="result"></span>
```

and controller action is:

```
public string linkfunction(string name)
{
    return  DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to this:

[ASP.NET MVC : AJAX ActionLink- Target an HTML attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488726/asp-net-mvc-ajax-actionlink-target-an-html-attribute)

Plus, you don't need to pass in the control name into your Action.

Comment: thanks, but my question confused you. i want to pass textbox1 value to my controler (as linkfunction parameter), so i need some way to pass textbox1.value in Ajax.ActionLink. i don't know how to do that.

Comment: Where you able to figure out how to accomplish the task? I'm in the same boat right now as you probably were; curious if you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, except I was using jQuery to make my ajax request:

```
$('#ajax-content').load('<%= this.Url.Action("Details", "Page", new { id = someJavascriptVariable }) %>');
```

I got it to work like this:

```
$('#ajax-content').load('<%= this.Url.Action("Details", "Page", ) %>' + '/' + someJavascriptVariable);
```

Or, in your case, it might look like this:

```
$('#ajax-content').load('<%= this.Url.Action("Details", "Page", ) %>' + '?name=' + textbox1.value);
```

Comment: to make it a bit cleaner you can pass in the key-value pairs as the data argument to the load method and jquery will handle the concatentation etc

Comment: $('#ajax-content').load('<%= this.Url.Action("Details", "Page") %>', {name = textbox1.value});

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Once it was pointed out to me that these functions return strings the rest fell into place - so, try the following

```
Ajax.ActionLink("mylink", "linkfunction", 
    new {name = __MyValue__}, new AjaxOptions 
    { UpdateTargetId = "result"}).Replace("__MyValue__", textbox1.value)
```

I haven't tested this snippet but something like this worked very well for me.

Good luck.